# Linux Based ODBC Connection to iSeries Suddenly Slow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, odbc, ibm-midrange

I have a Python application residing on Ubuntu Server 14.04.04 x86 that connects via ODBC to an iSeries (AS400) instance for reading data. This application has been in production on the same server for almost a year and everything has worked great.

Last week, for whatever reason, the SQL queries became slow to the point where the application was unusable. For testing purposes I configured a Windows 7 pc with the iSeries ODBC connection and copied over the application files. The application runs flawlessly and the SQL queries are executing quickly without any issues. I have since built a new Ubuntu server instance and have configured everything accordingly. On the new Ubuntu instance, the queries are still slow however, the queries on the Windows box are running like they should.

Can anyone shed some light as to what would cause the sudden slow down in query execution time using the Linux based ODBC connection?

Comment: this is with DB2? Seems likely that it is an indexing issue, (update statistics in Sybase-speak) and that when you  run the Windows query the scan is in the cache. Note the low # follower for your `ibm-m` tag. Change to a tag for the DB you are using or indicate in your Q that you're using ISAM or whatever for data. Good luck!

Comment: Also, a lot of IBM-heads (AIX, etc) on http://ittoolbox.com . Might be worth posting there too. OH, and I don't suppose you did `traceroute` and other diagnostics before before you had your problem, that you could compare those stats with current? IMHO, seems unlikely that a completely unchanged system (excepting `update statistics`) will suddenly behave differently. If you figure it out, post an answer and you can accept your own solution after 48 hrs for valuable reputation points;-)  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using the iSeries ODBC connection for Linux, to my knowledge it is not the same as DB2 (but I could be wrong). The application files are identical, the only difference here is the host OS and the ODBC configuration (Linux ODBC vs Windows ODBC).

Comment: Yes, but  you said the Linux ODBC was working fine, and you haven't changed them (correct?). I think you best bet is to post in a ibm-centeric forum. As the ittoolbox has a strong AIX group, I would think there is probably an iSeries cadre as well. But AS400 is really outside of my experience, so won't be able to help further. :-( Good luck!

Comment: Python, so pyodbc? And we have to ask if any updates have been done. Also, is the new server instance on separate hardware? Are there different switches or other similar hardware that makes a different route from the Windows systems? It doesn't seem likely that anything on the iSeries would have much chance at making a difference as long as the same user ID connects in all cases.

Comment: Actually pypyodbc. No updates. The original server was virtual. Since posting the question, I have tried installing on a fresh install of Ubuntu and Debian on a dedicated physical machine with the same slow results. The switch is the same for all systems.

Comment: `Last week, for whatever reason, the SQL queries became slow...` _Something_ changed. I'd scour the various update logs carefully. (Is unattended-upgrades configured?) I'm not aware of any way the iSeries side has any idea if Windows or Linux is on the other end of the port (though I can imagine possibilities), so I'd start w/Linux. If you use pyodbc on both Windows and Linux, does the same slowdown appear? (Should help isolate the problem.) The pypyodbc should naturally be noticeably slower.